# accessing laravel routes in vue component attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I am trying to access a named laravel route in my Reply.vue file. What i am trying to do is pass this route as an attribute to my **reply** component. But while compiling i get the following error:

```
invalid expression: Unexpected token : in

http://tddforum.com/thread/reply/10

Raw expression: :route="http://tddforum.com/thread/reply/10"
```

As you can see the value of the route is correctly assigned to the **:route** attribute but the page wont load due to the error stated above. Here is the first line of my reply component:

```
<reply :attributes="{{ $reply}}" :route="{{ route('reply.update',$reply->id) }}" inline-template>
```

what is wrong here?

Thanks,
Yeasir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `v-bind` which evaluates the value as JavaScript, but you are actually passing a string literal, so simply remove the `v-bind` (the colon):

```
<reply :attributes="{{ $reply}}" route="{{ route('reply.update',$reply->id) }}" inline-template>
```

If `reply` is also a string then you will need to do the same for that as well.

Comment: Yes, that worked!! And now have a better understanding of how the binding works. Thanks a lot :)